# Open a video from Synology File Station directly in VLC

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, streaming, synology, synology-diskstation

I have a Synology NAS, with some videos stored on it.

- At home I can access the video using SMB shares, and open them with VLC as if they were on a local disk
- from the internet on a mobile device, I can use the Synology DS File app to browse the content of the NAS. When I try opening a video I can play it either in the built player of DS File, or in VLC. The video is streamed, no need to download it entirely before playing. I can see that DS File sends a (quite long) http link to VLC to play the video
- From a PC I can browse the content of the NAS through the HTTP interface on the NAS, but I can't play any video:

  - If I right-click on a video file and select "Play", a player starts in the browser but quickly tells me that the the video cannot be played
  - If I try pasting in VLC ("Media/Open a network steam") the http address that appears on the top of the player, nothing happens

The question is: how to open the video in VLC? Of course I can still download the video and play it once downloaded, but what I really want is to have it streamed from the NAS.

Comment: >From a PC I can browse the content of the NAS through the HTTP interface-- Is this URL a local URL or a public URL?

Comment: @Narzard Public URL, from the internet, thanks to a NAT rule on the router

Comment: What I am guessing is that since you login to the NAS over a public URL, you get an auth token associated with that login. When you are just copying the URL into VLC, that authorization header is not being passed along with it which denies you access to the stream. If this was not in place, anyone on the internet could stream your file with out having to enter credentials just by having that URL. That token is contained within your browser and you "lose it" when you paste that URL into VLC if that makes sense. The best way is to read the file straight from the NAS locally over SMB.

Comment: @Narzard Reading straight over SMB is what I'm doing at home. But outside from home I can't access through SMB (well, it would be technically possible, but I don't want to expose the SMB ports on the internet). Note that I also tried a few firefo plugins of the kind "Open in VLC" without success. That's a pity, as on iOS (and Android I guess) the DS File app is able to provide an appropriate http URL to VLC.

Comment: Look into setting up Plex Media Server on your home machine. You can port forward that and then have access to your entire video library by streaming from your NAS.